# Unable to Launch Node.js Application Inside Built Docker Container

Tags: node.js, containers, docker

I've built a docker container (node.js installed along with some project files) with the following Dockerfile:

```
RUN yum install -y openssl wget unzip gcc gcc-c++ tar make automake git
RUN curl -L https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | bash

[... Chef Related Stuff ...]

#Docker CMD
WORKDIR /var/node
CMD ["/usr/bin/node /var/node/lib/app.js"]
```

The container it builds is designed to use a shared directory with the local machine on which docker is being used. When I attempt to launch the built container (i.e. the one containing the `CMD ["/usr/bin/node /var/node/lib/app.js"]` portion) I find that the container is unable to launch:

```
US-C02NC26AG3QN:docker user$ docker run -d -v /Users/user/Documents/test_area/docker/nodejs:/var/node front/nodejs
db07b901e83fb45f19d00151129ce42b836cf2379d91cebea54de8b51add614b
2014/11/04 10:42:56 Error response from daemon: Cannot start container db07b901e83fb45f19d00151129ce42b836cf2379d91cebea54de8b51add614b: exec: "/usr/bin/node /var/node/lib/app.js": stat /usr/bin/node /var/node/lib/app.js: no such file or directory
```

However, if I omit the the `CMD ["/usr/bin/node /var/node/lib/app.js"]` section from the Dockerfile, rebuild the image, and launch the container in the typical way it works just fine:

```
US-C02NC26AG3QN:docker user$ docker run -d -v /Users/user/Documents/test_area/docker/nodejs:/var/node front/nodejs /usr/bin/node /var/node/lib/app.js
ab83f476bde812f179c461eacb954fc59da4bcc9e22f5b14fd71d257cd7ade40
US-C02NC26AG3QN:docker user$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
ab83f476bde8        front/nodejs:latest   "/usr/bin/node /var/   4 days ago          Up 3 seconds                            clever_lovelace
US-C02NC26AG3QN:docker user$ docker top ab83f476bde8
PID                 USER                COMMAND
19815               root                /usr/bin/node /var/node/lib/app.js
```

What is happening here? Why is it not able to fine the directory when the launch command is included in the build but able to find the directory when the launch command is used explicitly when starting the container?

Answer (score 0):

`CMD` with brackets implies you're giving all the arguments as a list.  So you'd need to do

```
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

You can also run it with bash as

```
CMD node app.js
```